# Как сделать, что бы прелоадер грузился, пока не загрузится сайт?

Tags: css

```html
<div class="sk-circle" id="preloader">
  <div class="sk-circle1 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle2 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle3 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle4 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle5 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle6 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle7 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle8 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle9 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle10 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle11 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle12 sk-child"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var preload = document.getElementById("preloader");
    var loading = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 64);

    function frame() {
      if (loading == 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        loading = loading + 1;
        if (loading == 90) {
          preload.style.opacity = "0";
        }
      }
    }
  })();
</script>
<style>
  .sk-circle {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-child:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 15%;
    height: 15%;
    background-color: #8AFF33;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: sk-circleBounceDelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out both;
    animation: sk-circleBounceDelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out both;
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle2 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
    transform: rotate(60deg);
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle4 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle5 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
    transform: rotate(120deg);
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle6 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(150deg);
    transform: rotate(150deg);
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle7 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle8 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(210deg);
    transform: rotate(210deg);
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle9 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(240deg);
    transform: rotate(240deg);
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle10 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle11 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(300deg);
    transform: rotate(300deg);
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle12 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(330deg);
    transform: rotate(330deg);
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle2:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
    animation-delay: -1.1s;
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle3:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
    animation-delay: -1s;
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle4:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
    animation-delay: -0.9s;
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle5:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
    animation-delay: -0.8s;
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle6:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.7s;
    animation-delay: -0.7s;
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle7:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s;
    animation-delay: -0.6s;
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle8:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.5s;
    animation-delay: -0.5s;
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle9:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.4s;
    animation-delay: -0.4s;
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle10:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.3s;
    animation-delay: -0.3s;
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle11:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.2s;
    animation-delay: -0.2s;
  }
  
  .sk-circle .sk-circle12:before {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.1s;
    animation-delay: -0.1s;
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes sk-circleBounceDelay {
    0%,
    80%,
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0);
      transform: scale(0);
    }
    40% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      transform: scale(1);
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes sk-circleBounceDelay {
    0%,
    80%,
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0);
      transform: scale(0);
    }
    40% {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      transform: scale(1);
    }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Сайт - https://www.zenplus.space/
Там видно, что прелоадер грузится быстрее сайта

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что Ваш прелоадер конкретно привязан ко времени, а не к загрузке содержимого.

Содержимое же должно приходить с сервера, как я понимаю, если нет, то уточните вопрос.

Вы должны воспользоваться ajax запросом, перед отправкой запроса вы должны будете показать прелоадер, а после завершения запроса и приход ответа от сервера скрывать прелоадер.

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  beforeSend: function(json) {
    // показываем прелоадер
  },
  success: function(json) {
    // скрываем прелоадер
  }
  ...
});
```

Comment: Если он привязан ко времени, как просто увеличить время?

Comment: @Евгений, допустим, что вы будете грузить картинки, тогда вы должны будете получить количество ваших картинок, потом 100 / *количество картинок* = процент загрузки 1 картинки и условие: если картинка загрузилась, то +процент загрузки 1 картинки