# Как правильно реализовать анимацию для загрузки формы

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, css3

При отправке формы пользователю будет показываться анимация загрузки: прямоугольник, который заполняется цветом.
https://codepen.io/Raneto4ka/pen/roKgaj

Сейчас время работы анимации фиксированная, 
`animation: loader-inner 6s linear  forwards;`
но она не всегда будет одинакова и зависит от разных факторов, так что заранее неизвестна.
Вопрос: как это вообще правильно делать если мы знаем текущее состояние, т.е. x% из 100 - готово. Т.е. мне надо строить анимацию прогресс бара не на основе её длительности, а текущего состояния.
Буду благодарна за любую подсказку.

Comment: Как отправка формы то работает? AJAX?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/928907/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не обязательно знать сколько времени займет загрузка. Между ее "скачками" `css` будет анимировать прогресс-бар за заданное в нем количество времени. В моем случае каждый скачек производится каждые 1500 мс., а анимация от одного состояния до другого занимает одну секунду, как это задано в `css`. В самом конце, когда `progress === 100` можно заметить, что анимация идет от состояния `progress === 100` до `progress === 0`, но и этот относительно большой скачек занимает одну секунду.

```js
let progress = 0; // 0 - 100

let int = setInterval(() => {
  document.getElementById("progress").style.width = progress + "%";

  progress += 20;
  progress = progress > 100 ? 0 : progress;
}, 1500);
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  background: gray;
}

#progress {
  position: absolue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="progress"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что именно непонятно? Как получать процент прогресса во время отправки? В ответе я как раз таки эмулировал процесс загрузки через `setInterval`, и сбрасывал прогресс только для того, чтобы показать, что любой скачок будет анимироваться за одинаковый отрезок времени.

Answer (score 1):

Ну если вы знаете текущее состояние, то можно слегка переделать прогресс-бар.

```js
function loader(perc) {
 $(".loader-inner").height(perc + "%");
}

// эмуляция текущего состояния для демонстрации
var currentPerc = 0;
setInterval(function () {
  var min = 5, max = 25;
  if (currentPerc == 100) {
    currentPerc = 0;
  } else {
    currentPerc += Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    if (currentPerc > 100) currentPerc = 100;
  }
 loader(currentPerc);
}, 500);
```

```css
.wrapper-spinner {
 height: 100vh;
 margin: auto;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.loader-spinner-progress {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 transform: rotate(180deg);
 width: 70px;
 height: 71px;
 border: 4px solid #C3CCD7;
 border-radius: 7px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.loader-inner {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #C3CCD7;
 height: 0;
 transition: height 0.25s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper-spinner container flex-column">
 <div class="loader-spinner-progress">
  <div class="loader-inner"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```